# Rate of convergence going from convergence in probability and uniform integrability to $L_1$ convergence

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_n = O_P(a_n)$ and are uniform integrability, can we get a convergence rate for $E(|X_n|)$?

By Markov inequality we get $E(|X_n|) = O (a_n) \implies X_n = O_P(a_n)$.

By Vitally Theorem we get that $E|X_n| \to 0$ if and only if $X_n \overset{P}{\to} 0$ and $\{X_n\}$ are uniform integrability.

This question is close: 
[Rate of convergence when going from convergence in probability to convergence in the mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413995/rate-of-convergence-when-going-from-convergence-in-probability-to-convergence-in)

But it assumes $ |X_n| \leq M$ with probability one. Which is the "best" possible uniform integrability condition I can think of.

Comment: Hint: given sequences $a_n, b_n \to 0$, you may construct $X_n$ such that $X_n = O_P(a_n)$ and $E|X_n| = b_n$.  Which shows that this is essentially hopeless.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I belive I was blinded by mi hopes.

Comment: @NateEldredge Why is it hopeless? I'm new to the convergence of random variables so I am not sure what point you are making. You have $X_n = O_p(a_n)$ and $E[X_n] = b_n = O(b_n)$ with $b_n \to 0$. So you have a rate of convergence $O(b_n)$ for the expectation, what is the problem?

Comment: The point is that $b_n$ is arbitrary.  So for example, even if you know that $X_n = O_P(\exp(-x^{5000}))$, this by itself cannot ensure anything about the speed of convergence of $E|X_n|$; you cannot for instance rule out the possibility that $E|X_n| = 1/(\log \log \log \log n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.

Consider $a_n$, $b_n$ positive sequences such that $a_n \to 0$, $b_n \to 0$. Let $U \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$ and

$$X_n = I_{[0, b_n]}(U)$$

It follows that $E(|X_n|) = b_n$ and they are uniformly integrable because they converge to $0$ in $L_1$ sense but the are also $ O_P(a_n)$.

Given $\varepsilon > 0$ for $n_0$ such that $b_n \leq \varepsilon \, \forall n \geq n_0$ we get that  $P( |X_n| > a_n ) \leq P( U \in [0, b_n]) = b_n \leq \varepsilon$ if $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: I don't understand why the answer is no (note that I am new to convergence of random variables). You have $X_n = O_p(a_n)$ and $E(|b_n|) = O(b_n)$ so you have a rate of convergence for the expectation? What is the problem?

Comment: @sonicboom  This examples shows how to construct a sequence of random variables that is $O_p(a_n)$ but converges arbitrary slow "$b_n$" in $L_1$ sense.